# How to configure on which server a VM is created in Oracle Cloud Control & Oracle VM Manager?

Tags: virtual-machines, cloud, oraclevm

The hardware configuration is fine and I can reach my two servers in my serverpool. The problem is that I have to use two different brand of servers on which server 1 has Virtualization Technology and server 2 doesn't.

Server 1 is the master of the pool and both servers has the VM Role. But the problem is that everytime a user creates a specific VM (like Windows Server 2008r2 or Solaris 11) Server 2 creates it but isn't able to run it because it lacks the Virtualization technology.

I tried to keep server 2 busy with a bunch of vm's to occupy some resources but still the vm was created on server 2.

Is there a way that both servers have the VM Role but that Server 1 creates these VMs?

This is a brief overview of my setup:

- Oracle Cloud Control 12c Release 2 (12.1.0.2.0)
- Oracle VM Manager 3.2 (3.2.2.520)
- Server 1: HP ProLiant DL380 G5, 8 GB Memory
- Server 2: Dell PowerEdge 2850, 12 GB Memory